# Logging out of sitecore site using asp.net membership provider

Tags: asp.net, sitecore

I have a sitecore instance with multiple sites.  If a external user visits one of the sites and logs in(asp.net membership) and then either closes the browswer or goes to a different site I need to logout the user.  Is this possible? I'm not too sure how to accomplish this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a standard membership provider, I can only think of 2 ways to do this:

1. (harder way) Move to a centralized identity provider model (i.e. if you have www.site-a.com and www.site-b.com having the authentication managed by www.some-other-site.com) so that all rules involving SSO, current status, etc can be held there.
2. (easier way) Have all layouts inherit a piece of code that would check for logged in state on the current site and send back some javascript to send a request to a logout handler on the other domains in question to log them out of those sites.

The complexity here has to do with the fact that authentication is set on the client in the form of a set of cookies by default, and those cookies are owned by the domain that sent them.  This means site-a.com cannot kill the auth session for site-b.com, and this is why SSO providers have a place in the web software world.

Hope this helps!

Comment: do you know of any examples for option 2?